# how to make a form field not part of the submitted form

Tags: python, django

I have an extra field in a django form that triggers javascript to change the fields in other forms:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_extra_form_field = forms.ChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["field1", "field2"]

    field_order = ["field1", "my_extra_form_field", "field2"]
```

How can I ensure that `my_extra_form_field` is not included in the submiteed form?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your javascript in template:

```
// jQuery
$('#my_extra_form_field').removeAttr('name');

// Javascript
document.getElementById('my_extra_form_field').removeAttribute('name');
```

Comment: i am still getting an error in the form causing it to be invallid `[ValidationError(['This field is required.'])]`

Comment: Do same with `required` attribute or just make this field not required.